# Hibernate execute JDBC statement much slower

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, jdbc

TL;DR Same SQL query, when execute in hibernate, takes 70+ seconds, when execute using sql developer, takes only 1.5 second

I discovered that when a particular query is executed by hibernate, it takes much longer than if I take the generated sql and run it in a sql client.
for example, after enabled hibernate statics, I can see in the log

***67839913762 nanoseconds spent executing 2 JDBC statements***; which equals ***1.13 minutes***

However, if I take the generated sql and run it, it only takes max of **1.5 seconds**.

Can anybody points me to what are the possible cause of this difference?
My understanding is, the time for executing the JDBC statement is entirely up to the DB right?
If the SQL is the same, how come it’s so slow when it’s executed by hibernate?

samle entity class

```java
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class GpCustomer {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "CUSTNO")
  private String custno;

  @Column(name = "COMPANY")
  private String company;
}
```

sample repository

```java
@Repository
public interface GpCustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<GpCustomer, String> {}
```

sample service

```java
 public Page<GpCustomer> findAllCustomers() {
    Pageable limit = PageRequest.of(0,10);
    return GpCustomerRepository.findAll(limit);
  }
```

Update:
hibernate statistics

```
Session Metrics {
    137214920 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    18734658 nanoseconds spent preparing 2 JDBC statements;
    67839913762 nanoseconds spent executing 2 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    16386 nanoseconds spent executing 2 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the SQL statement generated by hibernate; the SQL run in the SQL client; the explain plans for both queries. We cannot debug code we cannot see.

Comment: @MT0 thanks for replying. The thing is, I can't even reproduce it myself. In the same code base, all other entities are working fine. With one entity, the query executed by hibernate is exceptionally slow. The generated query is like this `select dnbgpcusto0_.custno from apps.some_oracle_view fetch ? rows only`. If I take this generated sql and run it, it only take 1.5 second. That is the reason I want to ask. Because executing the JDBC statement(the sql) is DB's job, how can there be a difference when executing the same sql? Just looking for an idea of where to look for the root cause.

Comment: It almost look like DB is treating hibernate differently by deliberately slowing the same query

Comment: What is the SQL client you are using to test it (and what is the `?` for the fetch size). If you test it in SQL developer then it will default to fetching only the first 500 rows and then when you scroll down it will fetch the next 500 rows (etc.) so if you are fetching 20k rows then 1.5 seconds for 500 rows and 60 seconds for 20k rows sounds about right.

Comment: I'm setting the ? to 1, 10, 100 for comparison. just using the intellij database to connect to oracle. using the database tool run the query, even for 100 record, it takes less than 1.5 seconds. Setting the same size in the java service, it takes 1+ minute

Comment: @MT0 I just ran the same sql in multiple places, oracle sql developer, vscode oracle extension, intellij db view. The result is consistent, no matter the size(number of rows), query return within 2 seconds. However, same query run by hibernate takes 1 - 3 minutes. Is it possible that oracle can discriminate certain jdbc connection?

Comment: @JSNoob - In theory, sure, Oracle could probably get enough information to figure that you're using Hibernate to connect.  But it would be silly for them to use that information to intentionally slow your query down.  As others have asked, get the actual query plan from the session that Hibernate is using (and the actual query Hibernate is using).  It is conceivable that your Hibernate session has changed some session-level settings that have caused Oracle to pick a less efficient plan for this query but that is just speculation without a reproducible test case.

Comment: @JSNoob did you find anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason for such a behavior is that Hibernate actually fetches all the data and a SQL client might only fetch a few rows. Materializing all rows like Hibernate does obviously takes longer.

Another possible reason is that the optimizer treats the "literate SQL" which your SQL client most probably executes differently and performs better than the parameterized version that Hibernate uses. Hibernate uses `PreparedStatement` with parameter markers, so such statements are more generic and the optimizer might be pessimistic about its estimates when planning the query. A "literate SQL" i.e. without parameter markers doesn't have that problem. The optimizer will create a special query plan exactly for that SQL.

To do a fair comparison and rule out these pitfalls, write a JDBC program that uses `PreparedStatement` and parameter markers that reads all the data i.e. goes through the `ResultSet` to the end. Then you can compare the runtimes.

If you are affected by the second option, talk to your DB admin about this. I know Oracle has some option to peek for parameter values during optimization, so that might help.